# Casting method arguments of a Generic Class

Tags: c#, .net, generics, casting

I've made a generic class that saves and queries objects from a flat file. I keep having to change the method arguments to objects so I can cast them and I'm wondering if I'm going about this the right way...

**'T' will always inherit 'FlatFileRecord'**

This does not compile:

```
public class FlatFile<T>
{
   public void Save(T record)
   {
      FlatFileRecord castedRecord = (FlatFileRecord)record;
      castedRecord.RecordNumber...
   }
}
```

This compiles but seems to defeat the whole point of a strongly typed generic class:

```
public class FlatFile<T>
{
   public void Save(object record)
   {
       FlatFileRecord castedRecord = (FlatFileRecord)record;
       castedRecord.RecordNumber...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If T is always going to be derived from FlatFileRecord, then constrain it that way:

```
public class FlatFile<T> where T : FlatFileRecord
{
   public void Save(T record)
   {
      FlatFileRecord flatRecord = record;
      flatRecord.RecordNumber...
   }
}
```

If you need to make do without the constraint for some reason, you can cast to object and then back down again:

```
public class FlatFile<T>
{
   public void Save(T record)
   {
      FlatFileRecord flatRecord = (FlatFileRecord)(object)record;
      flatRecord.RecordNumber...
   }
}
```

Comment: I knew there would be a simple way to do it! I should probably use 'where T : FlatFileRecord' to enforce it. I think I need to read some more about generics...